# How to convert yolov5 trained model into tflite in google colab to install on mobile app?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-lite, training-data, yolov5

I have used **Yolov5** to train the model in google colab and how can I export the .tflite file of the trained model so that it can be used for mobile applications. Thanks for help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have the latest TensorFlow version 2.7.0 use the general method for that purpose that it is shown [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert#convert_a_savedmodel_recommended_):

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Convert the model
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir) # path to the SavedModel directory
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

Get back with your results and tag me if you have problems

Answer (score 0):

You can look in this github(https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite), i think you find something useful