# How to export YOLOv5 model to Tensorflow Lite

Tags: python, yolov5, tflite

I would like to ask some help. I've been struggling about how to convert Yolov5 model to Tensorflow lite. Any suggestion guys, how can I convert my Yolov5 model to tensorflow lite?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi! You can use TFLite converter API for conversion. Attaching a similar thread for reference.                                                     
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70670841/how-to-convert-yolov5-trained-model-into-tflite-in-google-colab-to-install-on-mo

Comment: Add code to your question so that we can understand what you have tried

Answer (score 2):

As sepecified in the official Yolov5 `export.py` (https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/export.py) you should run:

```py
python path/to/export.py --weights yolov5s.pt --include tflite
```